# Does "resources :controller" do anything other than creating 7 routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, resources

I know that writing `resources :pages` in routes.rb generates 7 routes for the :pages controller. Does it do anything else, or is creating 7 routes literally all that code does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*path helpers* and *url helpers* are also created. See here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default